# Foundation5 - Changing topbar breakpoint

Tags: javascript, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to change the topbars breaking point and have succeeded in some way. The visual way. But the part where you toggle it wont work until you go into small view size.

I've changed these settings. Is there something more I need to change in order to set the new breakpoint? JS? SASS?

```
$topbar-breakpoint: #{lower-bound($large-range)} !default;  // Change to 9999px for always mobile layout
$topbar-media-query: $large-up !default;
```

If I look at the meta for the topbar in the generated HTML. I find this tag:

```
<meta class="foundation-mq-topbar">
```

Which contains of:

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
  width: 64.063em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are editing the top-bar settings using `_settings.scss` file and not the `_top-bar.scss` file. You should not edit any of the Foundation components directly.

If you only change the `$topbar-breakpoint` value it should work. Leave the `$topbar-media-query` to its default value. You also should remove the `!default` flag.

```
$topbar-breakpoint: #{lower-bound($large-range)}; // Change to 9999px for always mobile layout
$topbar-media-query: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($topbar-breakpoint)})";
```

Comment: Great! I edited my answer to add that stuff about the settings file when I realized that was why you had the `!default` flags in there. I just happened to notice those were in the top-bar file and not in the settings file when I searched for the variables on github.